# cant get textbox value with space - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text box and a button , I writed a script that when clicked on button , create new textbox and Add it to form .

but when I have text Like `32 bit` and clicked on button It created a textbox with value like `32` .  I get inspect element and result was :

```
<input type="text" name="Options" class="field-input add-more" value="32" bit="">
```

my script:

```
 $("#add-more").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $("#more-text");

    var newTag = '<div class="col-lg-3"><input type="text" name="Options" class="field-input add-more" value='+ text.val() + ' /><span class="btn-sm btn-danger remove-me field-input">x</span></div>';
    $("#frm-fields").append(newTag);
    text.val("");
});
```

**please see below example .**

```js
 $("#add-more").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = $("#more-text");

        var newTag = '<div class="col-lg-3"><input type="text" name="Options" class="field-input add-more" value='+ text.val() + ' /><span class="btn-sm btn-danger remove-me field-input">x</span></div>';
        $("#frm-fields").append(newTag);
        text.val("");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row "  id="div-fields">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                
                <div class="form-horizontal" id="frm-fields-options">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="more-text" />
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="add-more">+</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frm-fields" class="row">
                     
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         
        </div>
```

Comment: `...value = "' + text.val().replace(/"/g, '&quot;') + '"...`

Comment: Even then, there's more stuff you would have to escape... I suggest creating each element using jQuery and inputting the attributes through jQuery's `.attr`/`.val` functions, as they will properly input the text...

Comment: @usandfriends  I try with your code but it doesnt work ,

Comment: What HTML do you see with my code?

Comment: @usandfriends result with your code is :`<input type="text"  value="32" bit="">`

Comment: I just tried my code with your example, and it works.... Not sure what you're doing.

Comment: I change `value='+ text.val() + ' ` to `value="' + text.val() + '"` and its work fine . just put in double qute `""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery method `.val()` to set text by converting HTML string in to a jQuery object.

```
 //Create a jQuery object
 var newTag = $('<div class="col-lg-3"><input type="text" name="Options" class="field-input add-more" /><span class="btn-sm btn-danger remove-me field-input">x</span></div>');

 //Set the text and append to form
 $("#frm-fields").append(newTag.find('input').val(text.val()).end());
```

```js
$("#add-more").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = $("#more-text");

  var newTag = $('<div class="col-lg-3"><input type="text" name="Options" class="field-input add-more" /><span class="btn-sm btn-danger remove-me field-input">x</span></div>');

  $("#frm-fields").append(newTag.find('input').val(text.val()).end());
  text.val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row " id="div-fields">
  <div class="col-lg-12">

    <div class="form-horizontal" id="frm-fields-options">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="more-text" />
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="add-more">+</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="frm-fields" class="row">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is a better way to do it actually. Good job!

Comment: your code it ok , but remove a button after input , please see my code snipped and your code , I put a button after textbox for remove it .

Comment: my result should like this : `<div><input type=text/> <span></span></div>` your result code like : `<input type=text />`

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to include the double-quotes:

```js
 $("#add-more").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = $("#more-text");

        $("#frm-fields").append('<div class="col-lg-3"><input type="text" name="Options" class="field-input add-more" value="' + text.val().replace(/\"/g, '&quot;') + '" /><span class="btn-sm btn-danger remove-me field-input">x</span></div>');
        text.val("");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row "  id="div-fields">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                
                <div class="form-horizontal" id="frm-fields-options">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="more-text" />
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="add-more">+</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frm-fields" class="row">
                     
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is not balanced .Opening and closing quotes for value attribute is not proper.

```
'<div class="col-lg-3"><input type="text" name="Options" class="field-input add-more" value='+ text.val() + ' />
```

Also you need check there is an empty space between quotes is this line

```
$("#more-text").val(" ");
```

JS

```
$("#add-more").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var text = $("#more-text").val();
              console.log(text);
            var newTag = '<div class="col-lg-3">'+
                              '<input type="text" name="Options" class="field-input add-more" value="'+text+'"/>'+
                                  '<span class="btn-sm btn-danger remove-me field-input">x</span>'+
                             '</div>';
            $("#frm-fields").append(newTag);
            $("#more-text").val(" ");
        });
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/h28mdmb7/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a `""` quotes around your value attribute as the value is space separated:

```
value="'+ text.val() + '"
```